# Features in Chess Diagrams

Tags: skak, chess

I've been using skak to display diagrams of chessboards in pictures, but I'd like a little more functionality. In particular, I'd like to be able to:

a) display only a portion of the board

b) indicate the importance of certain squares with stars

Can I do this with skak? Or is there another package to use?

Answer (score 3):

Use [chessboard](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chessboard). And perhaps instead of [skak](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/skak), [xskak](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xskak).

Comment: I had a feeling you'd be the first to answer this!